# Best Swift way to write Dictionary of String to Country

Tags: swift

I want my Swift class FinderForCountry to find the Country with the specified name.

The code should also remember any countries (by name) that have already been found.

My existing Swift class has a [String: Country] variable, and a method findCountry() that takes both a String and a function that takes a Country.

```
public
class FinderForCountry {
    private
    var mapOfStringToCountry = [String: Country]()

    public
    func findCountry(from string: String, _ functionThatTakesCountry: @escaping (Country) -> Void) {
        if let country = mapOfStringToCountry[string] {
            functionThatTakesCountry(country)
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let country = Country(string)
                self.mapOfStringToCountry[string] = country
                functionThatTakesCountry(country)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to write the code, or is there a better way?  For example:

```
public
class FinderForCountry {
    private
    var mapOfStringToCountry = [String: Country]()

    public
    func findCountry(from string: String, _ functionThatTakesCountry: @escaping (Country) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let country = self.mapOfStringToCountry[string] {
                functionThatTakesCountry(country)
            } else {
                let country = Country(string)
                self.mapOfStringToCountry[string] = country
                functionThatTakesCountry(country)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you need `DispatchQueue.main.async` at all?

Comment: Unrelated but the underscore in the signature is pointless. Completion closures don't have an external parameter label in Swift 3+ at all.

Comment: What does the initializer of `Country` do?

Comment: I don't think you need a dispatch async. I'd also rename my function to something else. `findCountry` sounds like it'd just return you the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed a better way.

The escaping completion handler and dispatching the code to the main thread make no sense as there is nothing which is executed asynchronously.

Just `return` the country.

```
public class FinderForCountry {

    private var mapOfStringToCountry = [String: Country]()

    public func findCountry(from string: String) -> Country 
    {
        if let country = self.mapOfStringToCountry[string] {
            return country
        } else {
            let country = Country(string)
            self.mapOfStringToCountry[string] = country
            return country
        }
    }
}
```